# Set "meta name" for rows and columns in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to "prettyfi" pandas confusion matrix which just returns a 2D-numpy array.

What I want to, is to add "legends"; one above the columns saying "Pred" and one for the rows saying "Actual"

something like this

```py
      
          pred
         0    1
        --------
       0|123  2
Actual  |
       1|17  200
```

(would be perfect if "actual" was rotated but thats just a minor thing).

I have the following lines for creating the dataframe w/o the meta-headers

```py
conf_mat = confusion_matrix(y_true = y_true,y_pred = y_pred)
conf_mat = pd.DataFrame(conf_mat)
... #missing lines for the last part
```

and  I have thought about using some multiindex but I cannot really make it work

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
conf_mat = pd.DataFrame(conf_mat)
```

Solution with `MultiIndex`:

```
conf_mat.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([['pred'], conf_mat.columns])
conf_mat.index = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([['Actual'], conf_mat.index])
print (conf_mat)
         pred     
            0    1
Actual 0  123    2
       1   17  200
```

Or solution with index and columns names (but some pandas operation should remeved this meta data):

```
conf_mat = conf_mat.rename_axis(index='Actual', columns='pred')
print (conf_mat)
pred      0    1
Actual          
0       123    2
1        17  200
```